# Salesforce create formula timestamp in a field when another field on a spreadsheet is filled in (QUIP)

Tags: timestamp, salesforce, formula, spreadsheet

I have a salesforce (QUIP) spreadsheet that people fill out when someone checks in. There are 5 fields. The first one is their Amazon log in(A2-A200). I want the last field that I created (G1-G200) to give a date/time timestamp when the Amazon log in field is filled in with a value. I am having problems building a formula to perform that action.

Answer (score 0):

What I was able to do is create an if statement "=IF(A1=1, NOW(), "00:00")" then format cell to display date/time. Only problem with this is that every time you refreshes the page it updates the time stamp to the most recent time. Hopefully this helps you start somewhere with this

Comment: Please format your code to a code fence and correct your grammar (refreshes -> refresh, time stamp -> timestamp). I can't do it because edit queue is full. Thank you.